# Nested For Loop (C++) Not Working Properly

Tags: c++

I am working on some programming homework and I am trying to use a `for-loop` in order to facilitate the process of the coding. Here is the loop:

```
#ifndef DIVSALES_H
#define DIVSALES_H

class DivSales
{
    public:
        DivSales(){ quarterSales[4] = {0}; };
        double getTotalSales() { return totalSales;}
        static void setTotalSales(double);
        static void addTotalSales(double);
        double getQuarterSales(int numQuarter) {return quarterSales[numQuarter];}
        void setQuarterSales(int numQuarter, double numAmount) { quarterSales[numQuarter] = numAmount;}
    private:
        static double totalSales;
        double quarterSales[];
};

double DivSales::totalSales = 0;
void DivSales::setTotalSales(double totalAmount) {totalSales = totalAmount; }
void DivSales::addTotalSales(double addAmount) {totalSales += addAmount; }
#endif // DIVSALES_H
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DivSales.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUMDIVS = 6;
    const int NUMQUARTERS = 4;
    double amount = 0;

    DivSales divs[NUMDIVS];

    for(int division = 0; division < NUMDIVS; division++)
    {
        cout << "Division " << (division + 1) << endl;

        for(int quarter = 0; quarter < NUMQUARTERS; quarter++)
        {
            cout << "Quarter " << (quarter + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> amount;

            divs[division].setQuarterSales(quarter, amount);
            DivSales::addTotalSales(amount);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Example of the output:

```
Division 1
Quarter 1: 500
Quarter 2: 500
Quarter 3: 500
Quarter 2: 500
Quarter 3: 500
Quarter 2: 500
Quarter 3: 500
Quarter 2: 500
Quarter 3: 500
Quarter 2:
```

What I am trying to do is make it so that when I have input the numbers for the 4 quarters of a division, that it will move onto the next division. However, after 4 inputs it is not incrementing the division variable of the `for-loop` instead it continues asking for more inputs. What is going on?

Comment: So it's infinite looping?

Comment: After you input 4 quarters it outputs "Division 1" again?

Comment: Would you mind showing us the rest of the code?

Comment: It's all ok with the code, the only thing that seems wrong is calling `setTotalSales()` for each division NUMQUARTERS times.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you pasted, so my guess is something's happening inside the setQuarterSales and setTotalSales functions.  Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger?

Comment: And/or traced it by hand?

Comment: I put up the code from the header.

Comment: http://ideone.com/SITYgn

Comment: @user2920558, replace `divs[division].setTotalSales(amount);` to `divs[division].addTotalSales(amount);`. Also what do you expect and what you got? Clarify your error please

Comment: For clarity, the problem is the inner loop stops after `NUMQUARTERS` times, which is 4?

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you see that makes you say, "after 4 inputs it is not incrementing the division variable of the for-loop."?  Does it ask for another input?  Does it stop executing?  Does it print out "Division 1" again?

Comment: Someone can maybe run with this better than I - the C++ I know is very old.  Is there an issue with the declaration of `quarterSales`?  Is this just a seg fault due to improper memory access that happens to happen after the 4th iteration?

Comment: I added more clarity to final part of the question. Though to brief it is asking me for more inputs infinitely. It never stops asking for them as if the `quarter` variable is not incrementing past 3 and thus jumping out of the `for-loop`.

Comment: In that case, try putting a cout in the loop, and print out the value of quarter.

Comment: I added the `cout` and also updated the question with the new code as well as example output with that code.

Comment: @user2920558, rebuild your project, if it won't help delete all the compiler output and rebuild it again, if it won't help too create new project and type this code again (or copypaste from stackoverflow, not from your old project). This code cannot produce the input you wrote

Comment: If my theory of memory corruption is correct, try entering in other values than 500.  501 would be good.  I expect you'll get different results in your loop.

Comment: This seemingly works on ideone but doesn't even compile with MS compiler. Which compiler did you use?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein That worked. Though what if the earnings are the same? It will break.

Comment: @Sarien I'm using MingW on CodeBlocks.

Comment: That wasn't a fix on my part - it was just a test to prove that you're somehow dealing with memory corruption.  Now that you've done that, I'm putting my vote behind memo1288.  The problem was that `quarterSales` was somehow corrupting your stack, and the value you were putting in happened to make it behave the way you saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what's causing that problem, it is in the file DivSales.h:

Change this line:

```
double quarterSales[];
```

For this line:

```
double quarterSales[4];
```

The problem was that you were not allocating memory for an array of 4 elements. To initialize it, change your constructor to this:

```
DivSales():quarterSales({0}){ };
```

You should also move the following line to DivSales.cpp, because otherwise I was getting a *multiple definition* error:

```
double DivSales::totalSales = 0;
```

Comment: I couldn't even get it to compile without this change.

Comment: Would you mind including the code as to how to dynamically allocate the memory for the array? My professor can't explain this stuff to save her own life.

Comment: @user2920558 No need for the array to be dynamic.  memo1288 gave details on how to statically allocate and initialize the array properly.

Comment: @memo1288 Does DivSales():quarterSales({0}){ }; initialize the entire array to 0? Which C++ version is that? MS compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: @Sarien Yes, it does. I tested it with MinGW 4.6.2 (dafault settings). Haven't tested it with the MS compiler, though.

Comment: Should I update the question and put up my final code so people who stumble upon this question can use it?

Comment: @user2920558 Not really, if your question has been resolved, just  [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41700/should-i-update-my-question-to-include-the-correct-answer) explains it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
divs[division].setTotalSales(amount);
```

you probably want:

```
divs[division].addTotalSales(amount);
```

But that is not what is causing your problem. Which I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It had completely flown over my head but I fixed it now.